# Is there a better way to pass a variable to the view layer instead of using controller?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Each time I create a controller route then I must pass a variable to the view layer :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Value("${api.url}")
    private String apiUrl;

    @Bean
    public String API_URL() {
        return apiUrl;
    }

}

@Controller
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private String API_URL;
        
    @GetMapping("/clients")
    public String viewListe(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("API_URL", API_URL); // here is the passing of the variable to the view layer
        return "client/client-list";
    }
}
```

It is tedius. So I want to know if there is a better way to pass this variable ; for example is it possible to pass it in the `@SpringBootApplication` part ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to [access a bean inside your Thymeleaf views](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#spring-beans). So in your case instead of passing the `API_URL` to every model as attribute just access the string like this: `${@API_URL}`